# How to sample a population based on an online survey form

Tags: sampling

I'm currently doing a research on TAM based on a prototype on my application. May I know how can I conduct a sampling on the data collected? (usually if interviews are conducted, we can randomly select respondents but in online environment, Im not really sure) Im planning to use a Google Form and share it to anyone that happens to suit the demographic requirement

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: hi may i know why?

Comment: You shall find the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).